# Finding all marks and show their prize

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table

```
+------+-------+--------+
| NAME | MARKS | SCHOOL |
+------+-------+--------+
| N1   |    80 | S1     |
| N2   |    90 | S2     |
| N3   |    75 | S1     |
| N4   |    70 | S2     |
| N5   |    55 | S1     |
| N6   |    75 | S1     |
| N7   |    70 | S1     |
| N8   |    80 | S1     |
| N9   |    60 | S1     |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Here I am trying to display Name, marks of the students of each School with Marks Descending order. Also, first Three highest marks should display as **First, Second, Third.**

So the finial output looks

```
+------+-------+--------+-------+
| NAME | MARKS | SCHOOL | PRIZE |
+------+-------+--------+-------+
| N1   |    80 | S1     | First |
| N8   |    80 | S1     | First |
| N3   |    75 | S1     | Second|
| N6   |    75 | S1     | Second|
| N7   |    70 | S1     | Third |
| N9   |    60 | S1     |       |
| N5   |    55 | S1     |       |
+------+-------+--------+-------+
```

I am trying with following code, I have tried three different queries not getting my output

```
<table width="100%" border="1">  
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Marks</th>
<th>Prize</th>
</tr>
<?php                     
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE SCHOOL= 'S1'
ORDER BY Marks Desc");

//$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable  AS t1  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT(Marks) 
AS best_marks FROM myTable WHERE SCHOOL= 'S1' ORDER BY Marks DESC LIMIT 3)
AS t2 ON t1.Marks = t2.best_marks ORDER BY Marks DESC, Name ASC";   


/* $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE SCHOOL= 'S1' AND

 LEFT JOIN
 (select Marks from myTable order by Marks desc limit 1) AS max1
 ON myTable .Marks=max1.Marks
 LEFT JOIN
 (select Marks from myTable order by Marks desc limit 2,1) AS max2
 ON myTable .Marks=max2.Marks
 LEFT JOIN
 (select Marks from myTable order by Marks desc limit 3,1) AS max3
 ON myTable .Marks=max3.Marks;

 ORDER BY Marks Desc";
 */


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo ucfirst($row['Name']);?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['Marks']; ?></td>

<td>

</td>
</tr> 
<?php   } ?>   
</table>
```

Comment: Your code isn't valid. I assume your not trying to run code in /* */. You have SQL statements just willy nilly in your code which will result in compilation problems. Your first query looks fine.

Comment: And your table example don't match with your result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select t.NAME, t.MARKS, t.SCHOOL,
       if(prize=1,'First', if(prize=2,'Second', if(prize=3,'Third',null))) as Prize
  from
    myTable t,
    (select m.marks, @prize := @prize + 1 as prize
      from (select distinct marks 
              from myTable 
             where SCHOOL= 'S1' 
              order by marks desc
            ) m,
            (select @prize := 0) p
    ) as mp
  where t.marks = mp.marks
    and t.SCHOOL= 'S1'
order by t.marks desc
```

Here you can see at fiddle:

New fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3635/28

Comment: @user2594154 Try now please

Comment: Great Mr. jorge Campos. Thanks a lots. Code working fine... thanks. you helped me a lot.